# How to select record from a table, where sum of a column equals a certain value?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a table `campaign`

```
capaign_id | offers_count
-------------------------
1          |       1
2          |       1
3          |       4
4          |       3
```

I am trying to select campaigns whose sum of offers_count is equal to 7, that is campaign 3 and 4.

Comment: Do you want to find all combinations in group of two campaigns whose sum of offers_count is 7?

Comment: Or you want to find all combinations from all campaigns whose sum of offers_count is 7 ?

Comment: No, i want to select campaigns whose aggregate sum of offers_count is 7. @GurwinderSingh

Comment: If it is all campaigns you want, then I think you should do it in a procedural way.

Comment: You have 4 different campaign_id's. There are no "aggregate" sums. Did you mean to have `campaign_id = 3` where you have `campaign_id = 4`?

Comment: is it for sum of pair? or if you would have (5,1) rows, you would like to get all rows (capaign_id:1,2,5,4), cos (1+1+1+4) and capaign_id(3,4) cos (3+4)?.. and would you want capaign_id =3 two times then?..

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution might be

1) Pluck `campaign_id` and `offers_count`

```
YourModel.pluck(:offers_count)
#=> [[1,1], [2,1], [3,4], [4,3]]
```

2) Then solve the subset sum problem against second elements [keep first/zeroth for reference]

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19488950/4481312

below code is also from SO post, but I weren't able to find the thread right now.

```
def subset_sum(array, tot)
  (1..array.size).each_with_object([]) do  |n,arr|
    array.combination(n).each { |a| arr << a if a[0][0].reduce(:+) == tot }
  end
end
```